# Agrupar las filas de una consulta en oracle

Tags: oracle

Necesito poder obtener el campo descripción concatenada en un solo campo, algo así como el `GROUP_CONCAT` de MySQL. He estado buscando y con la función `LISTAGG` parece que sirve pero me está arrojando un error como de sintaxis.

Esta es la consulta con la que estoy intentando hacer lo que necesito:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG ( descripcion ,' ' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY codigo ) FROM DEVOLUCIONES WHERE codigo IN (546,547) GROUP BY codigo;
```

pero me está saliendo el siguiente error:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Lo que deseo obtener es algo así:

La consulta normal me devuelve una tabla así

| Devoluciones |
| --- |
| Error al grabar |
| Periodo fuera |

y deseo algo así

| Devoluciones |
| --- |
| Error al grabar, Periodo fuera |

Comment: Sólo quita la cláusula `WITHIN GROUP(...)` dado que ya agrupas con `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ya lo he intentado, de esa forma aparece en algunas paginas.que he consultado y de igual forma sale el mismo error, segun lo que he consultado es algo de sintaxis pero no encuentro en donde

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Oracle estás usando?

Comment: 10g Release 10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de buscar por varios días encontré que la función `LISTAGG` solo esta disponible para la versión 11g en adelante, para poder realizar la consulta que necesitaba encontré la función  `WM_CONCAT` espero alguien mas le pueda servir

Les dejo la consulta como quedo finalmente

```sql
SELECT WM_CONCAT(Descripcion) FROM   devoluciones WHERE  codigo IN (546,547);
```